# Recoding values based on two vectors (levels and labels) with identical labels and multiple values to replace

Tags: r, r-factor

I am trying to re-code values of a vector based on some levels and labels. Importantly, I can have a multitude of value to replace (levels) with a multitude of other value (labels) and I don't know in advance how many I have. Additionally, two levels can have the same label.

Here is an example: I have a vector "a". I would like to re-code each value in "a_levels" by the corresponding labels in "a_labels".

```
a = c(5,6,5,5,7,8,7)
a_levels = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
a_labels = c('a', 'a', 'c', 'd')
```

I can assume that the first value of a_levels corresponds to the first value of a_labels etc.)

So I would like to get

```
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "d" "c"
```

Importantly, I have some constraints that do not allow me to apply so commons solutions:

1) Note that a_labels contains the label "a", twice, so I cannot use

```
factor(a, levels = a_levels,
       labels = a_labels)
```

2) In my data I have a lot of value to replace, and I even don't know
in advance which levels I need to replace with which labels.
I only get the two vectors a_levels and a_labels 
For these reasons I cannot use several ifelse() statements, or the recode function from dplyr.

```
recode(a, 
       '5' = 'a',
       '6' = 'a',
       '7' = 'c',
       '8' = 'd')
```

because I don't know the values and labels in advance.

It should be simple to do that, but I did not find a way.

Comment: Try `a_labels[match(a,a_levels)]`.

Comment: Want to write it as an answer? I think it could be of interest for a lot of problems dealing with re-coding

Comment: It's almost certainly a duplicate question and answer. `nicola` probably knows that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to nicola. The following works very well.

```
a_labels[ match(a,a_levels) ]
```